# Websphere and ibm-application-bnd.xmi file issue

Tags: maven, websphere-7, role, maven-ear-plugin

My web application (enabled with basic authentication for security) builded through maven and deployed in websphere. When I am mapping security user roles to respective group websphere server internally creating ibm-application-bnd.xmi with my role group mapping configuration. For minimizing mapping for role - group when each time deploying my ear, I copied and included the ibm-application-bnd.xmi inside my Ear's META-INF folder which created by server.My Ear structure(META-INF folder,application.war file). But websphere doesn't consider that ibm-application-bnd.xmi file and my role -group mapping is not done automatically. But I tried with sample dynamic webproject(no maven usage here manually built EAR using RSA) and did the same thing it works fine and role - group mapping done automatically using that ibm-application-bnd.xmi which I included in the ear.

I don't know what thing causing this issue. Is this problem with my ear structure build by maven, please help me to solve this.

Comment: Can you please update your question so that it shows the structure (content) of your EAR file. Please also add the content of the ibm-application-bnd.xmi file.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this for WAS 6.1 by putting the ibm-application-bnd.xml in src/main/**application**/META-INF. This gets picked up by the maven-ear-plugin as earSourceDirectory, so it gets bundled in the correct place.

If you put it in src/main/**resources**, it doesn't get packaged.

Comment: Thanks greyfairer, i am able to include that .xmi file in correct place but my server didn't refer that one for my role group mapping configuration.that the problem i am facing here.

Comment: I tried src/main/application/META-INF this way also , but my ear is not deploying properly, it throwing Ear corupted error while deploying.